# How to do successive authentication for Okta SAML followed by Azure AD Oauth?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

**What**

I have a unique requirement in that there is an application (springboot) that needs to be protected by 2 authentication providers in succession. That is, a user will be authenticated first by Okta and THEN by Azure AD in succession. It's not either/or, but BOTH authentication methods in that order.

**Why**

Because Okta provides us with a unique security requirement that is a must have, and Azure AD token is needed for accessing Microsoft resources.

**How**

What I have researched and done so far:

1. Searched for examples but have only found where there are multiple auth providers to choose from; nothing related to where multiple providers are used simultaneously.
2. Created a different app that sits in front of my main app and only does Okta authentication. It acts as a reverse proxy. I have had some success with it.
3. Contemplated writing my own AuthenticationProvider and AuthenticationManager that implements the auth flow for both Okta and AAD. This is my last resort since it would involve a lot of trial and error since I have never done this before.

I would prefer having a single app with implements both auth flow. What is the best way to do this? What all interfaces can I implement, classes I can extend and how can I wire these together to make this work?

I would appreciate help in any form.

Comment: I'd consider going the other way around - that is, placing a reverse proxy in front of your app which does AAD authentication and adds the token to the request headers, and then doing Okta authentication in the main app.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you please explain why you'd consider the other way around? It's a security requirement to put okta in front since it provides us with "Device ID Trust" flow. And the Device ID must happen first before anything.

Comment: Oh. It's because from my experience,  it's best to get authentication with AD out of the way first, as it's complicated and can lead to many possible errors. Also, confining AAD auth to a reverse proxy service will enable your main app to be simpler.

Comment: Hey, can't you integrate Azure AD as Identity Provider (IdP) into your Okta? I just don't know all the requirements.
At least this way you don't need to solve syncing of user accounts between Okta and Azure AD and you still have both in your authentication flow. Also, you can add any additional custom claims to your token. 
But if you must do it in two steps then I'd look into a custom AuthenticationProvider and filters.